# how to display facebook analytics on custom php page without login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

I am creating a web application using php for my client. Client's requirement is to display facebook analytics data/info/graphs (means all the things which are visible in facebook analytic dashboard) in that web application which are developing so that he will not have to go to facebook to check that.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Read the documentation. It's what developers do. According to your profile, you are one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about facebook-analytics, so I shouldn't be commenting here, but I think your client is asking for a lot. Logging into a dashboard is such a small effort. I think your client doesn't realize what is needed to fulfill this requirement. I hope you get the properly paid for this job.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let me recommend to use Facebook Analytics custom dashboards feature.
2. We do not provide public API to query Facebook Analytics in same way our Web UI does.

Comment: ok, let me check Facebook Analytics custom dashboards. Thanks @elize